# How can i display two images in singlr table row?

Tags: css, background-image, datatables

I am using jQuery DataTables to display data and I am assigning class to Table row using `DT_RowClass` attribute of DataTables. Depending on some conditions, I assign classes to every row and got struck where I have two classes for row and both of them need to display an image in that row.

**Code**

I have row like: `<tr class="firstImage secondImage"></tr>`

both `firstImage` and `secondImage` has css like `.firstImage  { background: url("img/firstImage.jpg") no-repeat 0px top; }` and same for `secondImage` with different Image and 125px as position.

I only get one Image at a time, Is there any way in `CSS` where I can get both Images to display in a row at same time. I think as both `css` classes has common `background` attribute, one overwrites another, but I cant seem to find a solution.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do whatever you do using divs and not tables. But if you decide to stick with tables, you'd need to put those image classes to the two `td` elements inside the `tr`, not on the `tr` itself; or change the CSS rule from `.firstImage {...}` to `.firstImage td {...}`. That way you'll attach background to the `td` elements.

Answer (score 0):

try:

`<tr><spanclass="firstImage"></span><spanclass="secondImage"></span></tr>`

Comment: I cant change ````<tr>```` attributes as they are created by jQuery DataTables